# Dropbox usage without being installed

Tags: macos, dropbox, screen-time

I saw high usage on the Dropbox app last night, without having ever installed this app.
Any explanation?

[image]

[image]

```
find: ./Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/private/var/mobile: Permission denied
./DaisyDisk.app/Contents/Resources/STIconCloudDropbox.pdf
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacResRetina.bundle/Contents/Resources/share_dropbox.png
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacResRetina.bundle/Contents/Resources/share_dropbox_dark.png`
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacResRetina.bundle/Contents/Resources/NewUI_Dropbox_Selected@2x.png
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacResRetina.bundle/Contents/Resources/share_dropbox_dark@2x.png
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacResRetina.bundle/Contents/Resources/share_dropbox@2x.png
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacResRetina.bundle/Contents/Resources/NewUI_Dropbox_Default@2x.png
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacRes.bundle/Contents/Resources/share_dropbox.png
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacRes.bundle/Contents/Resources/share_dropbox_dark.png
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacRes.bundle/Contents/Resources/NewUI_Dropbox_Selected.png
./zoom.us.app/Contents/Frameworks/zMacRes.bundle/Contents/Resources/NewUI_Dropbox_Default.png
./GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/app/static/gitignore/Global/Dropbox.gitignore
```

Comment: Short answer will be YES you have installed Dropbox before. What is in /Applications

Comment: @mmmmmm I added a screenshot. Can any of these applications use Dropbox on the background?

Comment: If it is text please copyit in as text It is difficilt to read a screenshot. Also ls /Applications is all that I was after

Comment: @mmmmmm it's not mentioned, but the command I ran was while being in `/Applications`.

Comment: Can you run `ps aux | grep -i dropbox` and add the result (as text)?

Comment: @nohillside `12080   0.0  0.0 408628368   1632 s000  S+    5:49PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox -i dropbox`

Comment: Hmm, strange. As an emergeny measure you could (in the Screen Time pane) limit the Dropbox process to 1 minute a day. This won't help to surface the mystery process though.